# Matlab - finding gradient

Tags: matlab, partial-derivative

Given the function:

$$v(x,y) = x + e^{-((x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2)}$$

I am supposed to calculate the gradient of this expression in Matlab for x defined in the interval -1:0.1:0.9 and y defined in the interval -2:0.1:1.9.  My task is to find the absolute value of the gradient of this function, and I'm supposed to do this two ways - first by calculating the gradient analytically by myself, and then by using Matlab's built'in gradient-function.  However, I get quite different results when I do this.  For the analytical part I did as follows:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(-1:0.1:0.9, -2:0.1:1.9);
analytic_partialx =  1 - 2*(x-1).*exp(-((x-1).^2 + (y-1).^2));
analytic_partialy = -2*(y-1).*exp(-((x-1).^2 + (y-1).^2));
abs_gradient = sqrt(analytic_partialx.^2 + analytic_partialy.^2);
```

When using Matlab's built-in function I did as follows:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(-1:0.1:0.9,-2:0.1:1.9);
v = x + exp(-((x-1).^2 + (y-1).^2));
[partialx,partialy] = gradient(v);
abs_gradient = sqrt(partialx.^2 + partialy.^2);
```

However, in the first case I get a matrix primarily containing values in the range of 1-1.5, whereas in the secand case I get a matrix primarily containing values in the range of 0-0.2.  So one of my approaches is wrong here since they should have been almost completely similar.  If anyone can help me by seeing what I do wrong here, then I would be extremely grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not near Matlab at the moment.  Does the gradient command have an option where you input all three of x,y,v?
Otherwise, you should divide your Matlab answer by 0.1, which is the value of dx and dy in the grid.

Comment: Dividing by the value of dx and dy turned out to fix the problem!  Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

The analytic gradient that you've computed looks correct to me.

If you look at the function in the neighborhood of (x, y) = (1, 1), it looks approximately like x + exp(something near 0, quadratic in x and y); that means that its derivatives in x and y are approximately 1 and 0, so the gradient magnitude must be nearly 1.0.

That suggests that the first computation is correct, and the second (whose answers are never larger than 0.2) is wrong. You might try revising that second computation to this:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(0.9:0.01:0.93,0.9:0.1:1.1);
v = x + exp(-((x-1).^2 + (y-1).^2));
[partialx,partialy] = gradient(v);
abs_gradient = sqrt(partialx.^2 + partialy.^2);
```

(here I've limited the domain of x and y to very near (1,1)) and then look at the actual partialx and partialy values that gradient returns to you, and see whether they're near 1 and 0, respectively.

Comment: Thanks!  I will try around a bit with this and see if it gets me anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is due to the dx and dy indeed - notice that one of the optional inputs to the gradient function is h: [fx,fy] = gradient(f,h) where h is the dx or dy (and if you have a different differential for both, you can enter both, see documentation of gradient).

So if your dx or dy is not 1, which is the default, you should also have h as the input (in your case h = 0.1) and then the results will match, up to numerical problems, without the need to multiply the result by 0.1. Essentially, it's the same as multiplying it later of course, but it may be more handy to put the h already in the gradient.

Good luck!